# Riemannian universal covering in absence of constant curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

It is known that if $M$ is a complete, connected Riemannian manifold of constant sectional curvature, then its Riemannian universal cover has to be isometric to one of the three models spaces: Euclidean space, the n-dimensional sphere, or hyperbolic n-space. However, I cannot seem to find anything in the literature regarding what can we say if the base space does not have constant sectional curvature.

For example, even if $M$ had (non-constant) everywhere negative sectional curvature, can we really say that its Riemannian universal covering is still isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$? Although this seems to be the only reasonable answer, the action of $\pi_1(M)$ on the universal cover would yield a constant curvature metric on $M$, which we do not have by assumption, so I am a bit confused on this point.

Any references or a brief explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since all these model spaces have constant section curvature, the universal cover cannot possibly be isometric to any of them. But it might still be, say, homeomorphic to them. Maybe even conformal, who knows.

Comment: The universal covering $\tilde M$ of a Riemannian manifold is locally isometric to the original manifold $M$, so you will not get constant curvature for $\tilde M$ unless $M$ had constant curvature. The main result about $\tilde M$ is the Cartan-Hadamard theorem.

Comment: We cannot say much more than: the universal Riemannian covering is simply connected and is locally isometric to the original manifold.

Comment: I am not sure what is the etiquette here, but I do think that all of the above make sense; I had forgotten the local isometry between $M$ and $\tilde{M}$. That certainly helps (and doesn't : ) ).